# Web driver exception on robot framework tests on jenkins

Tags: java, selenium, exception, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I have robot framework tests that when run locally, run fine. But when run on jenkins, after a fixed number of tests(nearly 14), start giving exceptions.

```
WebDriverException: Message: Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'xxxx', ip: 'xxxx', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Stacktrace:
```

What might be causing this? Do i need to breakdown big suites to smaller ones?

Comment: can you share the full stack trace info?

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all :

```
WebDriverException: Message: Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'xxxx', ip: 'xxxx', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

The error clearly says the following :

- Your *Selenium Java Client* details is not getting detected back as in **revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'**
- Your *WebDriver* variant details is not getting detected back as in **Driver info: driver.version: unknown**

Your main issue is the **version compatibility** between the binaries you are using as follows :

- Your *Selenium Java Client* version is **3.4.0** of **Apr 21, 2017** which is almost **a year** older.
- Your *JDK version* is **1.8.0_131** which is pretty ancient.
- Your *WebDriver* variant version is unknown to us.
- Your *Web Client* variant version is unknown to us.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *JDK v8u131* , *Selenium Client v2.4.0*.

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u162**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u162-relnotes-4021436.html).
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.11.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *WebDriverDriver* variant version to recent levels.
- Upgrade *Web Client* version to recent levels.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* base version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Execute your `@Test`.

Comment: If that is the case, why only few of the tests in the suite fail? Shouldn't all fail?

Comment: Of-coarse Passing and Failure of a Testcase depends on the `methods()` you invoke and the internal implementation of those methods maintaining _W3C Standards_